# Relate LokiJS with json and fetch data from Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, lokijs

Im using **Angular 4** for building an app, but for the moment i want to have data (in memory) like **LokiJs** do.

Can anyone help me how can i implement LokiJs on my Angular project and make it to communicate with my JSON.

Is there any `npm package` that can help me?